# Fibonacci Recursive, why fib(2) print two?

Tags: fibonacci

```
def fib(x):
  if x == 0 or x == 1:
   return 1
  else:
   return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)

print (fib(2))
```

my logic is:

```
1st fib(2-1)+fib(2-2) return fib(1) 
2st fib(1) return 1 ; 
3rd print 1
```

who can tell me what wrong with my thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic has an issue right here

```
 if x == 0 or x == 1:
       return 1
```

therefore

```
    1st fib(2-1) + fib(2-2) ; 
subdivide into fib(1) + fib(0);
    2nd fib(1) return 1 + fib(0) return 1;
    3rd 1+1 = 2;
    print 2;
```

Your *if statement state `if x== 0 OR x == 1: return 1;`*

Answer (score 1):

The first 5 terms of the fibonacci series are as follows:

```
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 3
```

Your code instead returns a series who's first 5 terms are these:

```
0 : 1
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 5
```

The reason your function doesn't return the correct values is because of this if statement:

```
if x == 0 or x == 1:
    return 1
```

This is of course, completely wrong. In order to get the correct numbers, you must modify your code like so:

```
def fib(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    elif x == 1 or x == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
```

This corrected function returns 0 if the argument `x` is 0 and 1 if it is 1 or 2.